# Interpolate values on Sorting in PSQL query

Tags: postgresql

In the database, I have a field as `status` which can have a value of

1, 2, 11, 12, 21, 22

1, 11, 21 Stands for processing

2, 12, 22 Stands for completed.

I am doing this query to get all data with sorting..

```
select se.*, cam.name, cam.exid, u.api_key, u.api_id from snapshot_extractors se
            left join cameras as cam on se.camera_id = cam.id
            left join users as u on cam.owner_id = u.id
            where lower(cam.name) like lower('%%') or lower(se.requestor) like lower('%%')
            order by se.status desc []
```

But when It sorts through `status`.. sorts works but in table formation where I am displaying the data, 22 and 2 means the same thing. but on sorting. either 2 will be up the list or 22 will be down or either way.

I am not getting any clue how I can make it work with sorting, so 22 and 2 can be at the top when I am sorting for completed ones.

Comment: Cast to text in sorting expression. `order by se.status::text desc`. Or maybe by last char then by value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort using an expression:

```
order by case 
        when se.status in (2, 12, 22) then 1
        when se.status in (1, 11, 21) then 2
        else 3 -- just in case
      end
```

This would sort rows with status "processing" before rows with "completed"

Comment: and where to put asc or desc?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq: after the `END` - but you don't need it as this already puts the rows processing first (you would only need `DESC` if you want those with "processing" at the end)

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other statuses than 1, 2, 11, 12, 21, 22, then

```
order by mod(se.status,2)
```

might be a little faster.